# matrix operation not returning correctly

Tags: octave

```matlab
R = [cos(pi/3) sin(pi/3); -sin(pi/3) cos(pi/3)]
[i,j]=round([1 1] * R)
```

returns

```matlab
i =

  -0   1

error: element number 2 undefined in return list
```

While I want `i=0` and `j=1`

Is there a way to work around that? Or just Octave being stupid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Octave is not being stupid; it's just that you expect the syntax `[a,b] = [c,d]` to result in 'destructuring', but that's not how octave/matlab works. Instead, you are assigning a 'single' output (a matrix) to two variables. Since you are not generating multiple outputs, there is no output to assign to the second variable you specify (i.e. `j`) so this is ignored.

Long story short, if you're after a 'destructuring' effect, you can convert your matrix to a cell, and then perform cell expansion to generate two outputs:

```
[i,j] = num2cell( round( [1 1] * R ) ){:}
```

Or, obviously, you can collect the output into a single object, and then assign to `i`, and `j` separately via that object:

```
[IJ] = round( [1 1] * R ) )
i = IJ(1)
j = IJ(2)
```

but presumably that's what you're trying to avoid.

---

**Explanation:**

The reason `[a,b] = bla bla` doesn't work, is because syntactically speaking, the `[a,b]` here isn't a normal matrix; it represents a list of variables you expect to assign return values to. If you have a function or operation that returns multiple outputs, then each output will be assigned to each of those variables in turn.

However, if you only pass a single output, and you specified multiple return variables, Octave will assign that single output to the first return variable, and ignore the rest. And since a matrix is a single object, it assigns this to `i`, and ignores `j`.

Converting the whole thing to a cell allows you to then index it via `{:}`, which returns all cells as a comma separated list (this can be used to pass multiple arguments into functions, for instance). You can see this if you just index without capturing - this results in 'two' answers, printed one after another:

```
num2cell( round( [1 1] * R ) ){:}
% ans = 0
% ans = 1
```

---

Note that many functions in matlab/octave behave differently, based on whether you call them with 1 or 2 output arguments. In other words, think of the number of output arguments with which you call a function to be part of its signature! E.g., have a look at the `ind2sub` function:

```
[r] = ind2sub([3, 3], [2,8])     % returns 1D indices
% r = 2   8

[r, ~] = ind2sub([3, 3], [2,8])  % returns 2D indices
% r = 2   2
```

If destructuring worked the way you assumed on normal matrices, it would be impossible to know if one is attempting to call a function in "two-outputs" mode, or simply trying to call it in "one-output" mode and then destructure the output.

Comment: Ho wow, thank you for the explanation, I really appreciate it !